# How to properly setup a verified mail signature?

Tags: ubuntu, email, gpg, signature, verification

I've renewed and imported my old self-generated GPG certificate. After setting the new expiration date I've uploaded my cert using `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --send-keys <key id>`

Receiving a test mail, Evolution reports that the mail contains a valid certificate that couldn't be verified.

I'm wondering how that should work. Following tutorials on the web, I could create any certificates for arbitrary mail addresses and just publish them on some cert server.

So how can I setup a *verified* certificate accepted by any mail receiver?
Is this even possible for accounts on public email providers, e.g. some-account@gmail.com?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **no**, self-signed certificates are not publicly trusted.

E-mail certificate verification is - just like in the case with SSL certificates for websites - a question of them being confirmed by trusted authorities. You can then use these to sign your mails in your mail client.

One may manually trust certificates from outside this system, but if any recipient is to see the certificate as trusted "by default", it must be part of the CA-system.

There are a few websites that offer free, trusted e-mail certificates for private users. As the offers change from time to time and I do not like to make it seem like an ad, I'll refrain from mentioning them here.

Comment: I was afraid I'm right and you confirm. Is there a way to get a free mail cert using an own domain `mail@example.org`, e.g. from let's encrypt?

Comment: I've delegated a smtp/imap to a 3rd party mail provider now and added my own domain there. So I could perform a challenge to prove the ownership.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Kleopatra** for gpg, certs and other key types. It is a graphical interface that 'helps' you create certs, keys, and then give you the option of uploading them to a Server. **Kleopatra** explains what Server, what the risks are, if any and more. You can install it via `apt install kleopatra`. When you first start it up you will want to go to ***Settings***, **Configure Kleopatra**, to change some settings to suit your needs.

Still, you are dealing with a Self-Signed Cert, which are almost never going to considered *Valid* because its a huge security risk.

I grabbed a few screenshots to show you, and imported the key for Burpsuite so I could show you that there is an option to "Look up on Server", but (I couldn't get a screenshot of this), if you right-click on any certs there is an option to **Upload to Server**.

As far as whether or not the second part of your question is possible, have you tried using **Thunderbird**? You can create a cert with a 'real' name and email address and Import it to Thunderbird. You can then choose whether you want TBird to Automatically pick the cert or Ask you each time.

[image: Server Options]